# I have create system.xml for system config value but not work

Tags: xml, magento-2.1.3, system-config, system-configuration

I have created one extension now i released i have also need some system config value where user can easily to handle this module. so i have created system.xml in adminhtml folder but its not work correctly.

Below my system.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="dd_invoice" translate="label" sortOrder="10">
            <label>DD</label>
        </tab>
    </system>
</config>
```

Please check Reply on this if any changes are needed.

Thanks

Comment: You have to create config.xml also To show that @Ajay Patel

Comment: can you please guide me how to do this?

Comment: I think config.xml its for set default value set. not require to create tab and config field.

Answer (score 0):

You have to Put these code in system.xml

file path:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="dd_invoice" translate="label" sortOrder="10">
            <label>Ewall</label>
        </tab>
    </system>
</config>
```

then You have to create config.xml

file Path:app/code/Extension/Module/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <dd_invoice>
            <general>
                <enable>1</enable>
                <time_insec>5</time_insec>
            </general>
        </dd_invoice>
    </default>
</config>
```

Comment: what is time_insec??

Comment: Those are my fields In tab..You can give your tab fields @AjayPatel

Comment: sorry dude this not work for me.

Comment: Chnage Sort order Once @AjayPatel

Comment: ohh... my site is down with this error  : Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

Comment: Is Your problem resolved @AjayPatel

Answer (score 0):

Create Sections In Order to Display. If there are no sections it wont be visible in Configuration

Try this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="DDD" translate="label" sortOrder="20">
            <label>DDD</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="mymodule" translate="label" sortOrder="20" type="text" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>My Module</label>
            <tab>DDD</tab>
            <resource>Namespace_Modulename::config_mymodule</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" sortOrder="1" type="text" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>General Configuration</label>
                <field id="active" translate="label comment" sortOrder="20" type="select" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Enable My Module</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section> 
    </system>
</config>
```

**Update**

Add the acl file in

yourmodulepath/etc/acl.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores">
                    <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores_settings">
                        <resource id="Magento_Config::config">
                            <resource id="Namespace_Modulename::config_mymodule" title="My Module"/>
                        </resource>
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Comment: No luck with this sorry

Comment: Have you tried clearing cache? What error are you getting ?

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

Comment: I assume the error is coming from somewhere else. This code works for me.

Comment: what is this config_mymodule?

Comment: that is resource defined in your acl. I have updated code for it.

Answer (score 0):

You should see:

The system.xml is a configuration file which is used to create configuration fields in `Magento 2` System Configuration. You will need this if your module has some settings which the admin needs to set. You can go to `Store -> Setting -> Configuration` to check how it look like.

Fore More:
https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/create-system-xml-configuration-magento-2.html